# deserialize with JSON a huge file android

Tags: java, android, json, serialization, deserialization

I have a 10M serialized file on sdcard in android. I need to deserialise it with jason. Can someone please tell me how to do this?
Can I deserialise in chunks of 1024bytes or something like this the file which is written on sdcard? I am working in an android project which cannot handle big files in just one stream due to memory allocation.

Need help!
I am new to jason and android handling big files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to deserialise in small chunks (using jason) a big file from sdcard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681627/is-it-possible-to-deserialise-in-small-chunks-using-jason-a-big-file-from-sdca)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the standard Android implementation of Android in parsing Json
http://android-pro.blogspot.com/search/label/JSON

another alternative is Google Gson library http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ which supports streaming.

### Example:

Suppose you want to parse a chunk of persons date:

**First:** create a class that maps the json response to your data type

```
class Person{
        @SerializedName("PersonName")
        public String name;
        @SerializedName("PersonAge")
        public String age;
        @SerializedName("PersonAddress")
        public String address;
    }
```

**Second:**to deserialize (parse) the Json response with Gson:

```
Gson gson=new Gson();
Type collectionType=new TypeToken<ArrayList<Person>>(){}.getType();
ArrayList<Person>persons=gson.fromJson(jsonResponse, collectionType);
```

Comment: could you please give me an example with GSon? How does it work? It takes a spefici chunk of data from a file and converts it in object?